# What needs to be passed in redirect_uri parameter to facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to add facebook authentication functionality in my android app. I want to generate code using this url : 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri=
I have app secret and access token. But I am not sure of the redirect_uri. If I pass some url like http://www.example.com/step, I am getting the following error response

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

Please help me with what should be the redirect_uri parameter.

Comment: If we are not talking about a web app here that just happens to be _used_ on an Android device, but a native Android app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

Comment: Yes, I am trying to call from my native android app, please tell me a solution for this, its a bit urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an adress that is in the domain you specified in your Facebook app. Facebook will only redirect back to urls in that domain. You can change your hosts file to point that url to 127.0.0.1 if you want to test locally, since it's a browser redirect.

Comment: I have added my domain in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs section in the advanced tab in settings, still its not working . Its throwing the same error.